# bizarre VC10 linker error

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

hey all, I just installed VC 2010 Premium Beta2 on my system and I migrated my old vc9 projects to it... everything seemed ok at first...

what's strange is that no matter what I compile I get the following error message:

1>  Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 6.00.8447
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.
1>
1>   ■/
1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "ERRORREPORT:PROMPT"; ignored
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file " ■/.obj"
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

the warning about errorreport is a little annoying but non-fatal... annoying because no matter which errorreport setting I choose, the warning stays... however the LNK1181 is fatal and even more frustrating because it seems to have no detectable cause.

my input list contains no .obj files, only various .lib files... furthermore, there is that strange block-like special ascii character in the name which I've certainly never typed anywhere. initially when this showed up I thought it must be some artifact of the vc9 to vc10 migration... and after spending 2 hours looking all over for the cause, it occurred to me to test whether or not it occurs with brand new projects... well sure enough it does!!

I create a BRAND NEW project... involving no migration, nada... just a brand new win32 project with the default afx files and so forth... I don't change any default setting and it gets this exact same linker error!

I hope somebody here can shed some light because this is very mysterious... at the moment the only other diagnostic method I can think of is to try to create a new workspace and add a new project to that and see if that works... ok just tried that and no dice... problem still persists.

anybody have some advice or seen this before?

Comment: Post the exact command line from the *build log*.

Comment: Do you have a copy of cl.exe in your system path?

Comment: hmm i'll post it with 2 lines since they only give me 600 characters



       Link:
         C:\COMMAND\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"F:\CODING\ACTIVE\PROJECT_BO_RD2_VISTA\Debug\OG_TEST.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\OG_TEST.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"F:\CODING\ACTIVE\PROJECT_BO_RD2_VISTA\Debug\OG_TEST.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT

Comment: /IMPLIB:"F:\CODING\ACTIVE\PROJECT_BO_RD2_VISTA\Debug\OG_TEST.lib" /MACHINE:X86 Debug\OG_TEST.res
         Debug\OG_TEST.obj
         Debug\stdafx.obj
         Debug\OG_TEST.exe.embed.manifest.res
         Â â– / 
     1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file "Â â– /.obj"
     1>Done Building Project "F:\CODING\ACTIVE\PROJECT_BO_RD2_VISTA\OG_TEST\OG_TEST.vcxproj" (build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.80

Comment: actually the full final bits is:
         Debug\OG_TEST.exe.embed.manifest.res
         Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 6.00.8447
         Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.
         
         Â â– / 
     1>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "ERRORREPORT:PROMPT"; ignored


very strange those Â â symbols I wonder what the hell they are

I don't seem to have CL.EXE in my path... according to the build.log CL.exe is being invoked with an explicit path

Comment: oh shoot!!!

that was it!!!

C:\COMMAND is where I stash tools I wrote and I seem to have left an old linker there

C:\COMMAND\LINK.EXE was a linker from 1999!!  probably vc6 or vc7 or some crap... omg haha... well problem solved, thank you everyone :) :)

Comment: In the future, note that you can edit your original post and put the build log there. There is no character limit there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an old copy of your pre-processor or linker (cl.exe, link.exe) in your system path.